# Reason not to implement Database.AllowsCallouts

Tags: apex, batch, callout

I have a number of batches all extending a base batch class that handles logging of sorts. Some of these batches do callouts, while others just handle data in Salesforce alone. It happened to me on several occasions that I forgot to implement `Database.AllowsCallouts` on new batches that do callouts, so I was thinking of simply adding it to my base class. This means that the batches that extend my base class that do not do any callouts will also implement that interface. Would this do any harm to the performance? Would there be any reason to specifically add it only to the batches that actually need it?

Comment: Great question - I also use a base batch/schedule/queueable class and wrap in this interface along with all the others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interfaces such as `Database.AllowsCallouts` or `Database.Stateful` can be considered as [Marker Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern). They do not bring any *overhead* to the implementing classes but it's a marker to the runtime virtual machine to treat any implementing classes in a special way. Although not specifically stated in Apex Developer Guide, but you can find a reference of [Marker Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_interfaces_abstractCmp.htm) on Aura Components Developer Guide.

The design strategy as if you want to implement at the parent or child classes are totally fine, you can take the call based on how much effort you want to spend in modifying the classes. If I were to write something like this, I would have included this interface at the parent level so that I don't have to individually modify all the child classes.

Comment: Database. Stateful can bring some sidefffects if the code is altering a few instance variables.

Comment: Thanks Jayant, this is what I would have thought, I'm glad to have it confirmed.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal haven't really tried out anything from performance front, but the reference was more to emphasize *marker interface* itself.

Comment: I would not be suprised if Stateful would have a larger influence on the performance than AllowsCallouts.